# Create a table with day of month as headers. PHP

Tags: php, date

I want to create a table like this...

```
 Oct-01 | Oct-02 | Oct-03 | Oct-04 | etc etc
```

Using whatever month it is now.

I'm using this to get the first day...

```
$first = date('01-m-Y',strtotime('this month'));
```

How can I increment this by the amount of days in this month?

Use `cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date(j), 2013)`?

But how to increment the first day.
I tried using '+1 day' in the `strtotime`, but nothing happened.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I didn't understand the question, but if you mean how can you add 1 day to your $first variable, I think [date_add](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php) does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's `DateTime` class can be used here. You don't need to use `cal_days_in_month` function to calculate the number of days in a month -- `DateTime` handles it automatigically. And it's a lot more cleaner and supports a wide range of dates.

Here's how:

```
$start  = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$end    = new DateTime('first day of this month + 1 month');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($period as $day){
  echo $day->format('M-d')."<br/>";
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/54140)

Comment: If you want the 0 in front of the single digit days it's `format('M-DD')`

Comment: @Casey: It already does that. See the demo. And `D` is used for something different (it displays the day -- Mon, Tue, Wed etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the DateTime object:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('first day of this month');
$days = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= $date->format('t'); $i++){
    $days[] = $date->format('M-d');
    $date->modify('+1 day');
 }
```

You could also add the whole date object to the array giving you flexibility later to use it however you want.

Comment: Just a note: this would output something like `Oct-TueTue`, `Oct-WedWed` which presumably isn't what the OP wants. See [this](https://eval.in/54144). :)

Comment: So it does. I must not be reading this correctly http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: +1: It is ok example without DatePeriod. p.s. your link is not about formating output date, it is about supported input formats. See output formats [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$days = array();
$maxDay = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('j'), date('Y'));
for($i = 1; $i<$maxDay; ++$i) {
    $days[] = sprintf(date('M')."-%1$02d", $i);
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($days);
```

Now you can do whatever you like with $days array...

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/fd1-1r2